# write each element(Key-value pair) of hashmap to different excel sheets in same workbook using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, hashmap, apache-poi

I want to write each key-value pair of the Hashmap to a different sheet in the same workbook.The Hashmap has the following values:

```
 SP001(key) :: 9087897867,8908789867,7896756789(value)
 SP002(key) :: 5241526352,4121451252,4152634512(value)
 SP003(key) :: 4152784524,4578451245,4152784596(value)
```

The key should be used to name the excel sheet and the value(containing numbers separated by comma) should be written in cells as displayed in image below

[image: Output Should be like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been involved with ApachePOI alot recently in my own project and I must say it can prove very useful. I threw this together without running it through an IDE or anything, so it might need a check, but you basically want:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
for(String key : yourMap.keySet()){
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(key);
    List<Integer> values = yourMap.get(key);
    int row = 0;
    for(Integer value : values){
        sheet.creatRow(row).createCell(0).setCellValue(value);
        row++;
    }
}
```

I've kept some sources I found quite handy that I like to share when I see ApachePOI brought up. If you want a brief overview of core class descriptions you can [view them here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_core_classes.htm) and if you want a boatload of examples, [here is a whole list of 'em](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html#xssf-only) from Apache's site. Pretty useful stuff. Hope this helps